# PHP: How to sanitize a natural number (positive INT)?

Tags: php, filter, sanitization

From [PHP sanitize filters](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php) list there is one option to sanitize integers:

> FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT - Remove all characters
>   except digits, plus and minus sign.

If we use:

```
filter_var($var2San, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

This will clean dots `.` and commas `,` but the `+` and `-` signs remain. E.g.: `++++ ---  1.110,4 <b>m<sup>2</sup></b>` is sanitized to `++++---111042`. Ideally the [`filter_var`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) would return `false` when the number was 0, i.e. the number would have to be a [natural number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number), more specifically, a positive integer.

Therefore a `FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_NATURAL` would be handy... Is there a workaround for this or do I need a RegExp?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Using regexp functions seems overkill, since there is another way to use the `filter_var` function:

```
filter_var($var2San, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,
           array('options' => array('min_range' => 1)));
```

The FILTER_**VALIDATE**_INT is listed under the [PHP filters flags](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.flags.php) and without defining a specific flag (in the `$options` array), the `filter_var` will detect and return the number if it is valid, returning `FALSE` otherwise. Examples:

- `-1` → `FALSE`
- `0` → `FALSE`
- `1` → `1`
- `+ 1` → `FALSE`
- `+2` → `2`
- `++3` → `FALSE`
- `4+` → `FALSE`
- `5.6` → `FALSE`
- `7,8` → `FALSE`

This guarantees that the number you test is a *natural number* (a **positive integer** without any other characters besides digits around it, except a `+` at the left). Even if it has a `+` ahead of it, it will only return the number itself.

There is a small setback though, if the number is over 2147483647, it will also return `FALSE` ([maximum positive value for a 32-bit signed binary integer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2147483647#In_computing)).

Comment: There's also `ctype_digit()`, which doesn't not have a limitation on its maximum value, but also does not allow "+", thousands separators, a decimal place, etc.  It is literally as if you had used the regex "^[0-9]+$" to validate your string, though obviously much faster.

Comment: @Ghedipunk Despite only returning `false` or `true` [ctype_digit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php) seems a very good alternative, appreciated!

Comment: Very clean. Love it.